# Can't get child magento theme to work correctly, no changes are made

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento Ver. 1.8.1.0 and I'm trying to make a child theme of a free theme I've downloaded. I already try to create the following folders copying all files I need from the original theme

```
public_html/atacadomiranda.com/app/design/frontend/my-pack/my-theme
public_html/atacadomiranda.com/skin/frontend/my-pack/my-theme
```

Also tried to make a folder called 'custom' inside of the main theme folder where is 'default' folder. Make all changes in DESIGN section of CONFIG ADMIN SESSION. I tried to do some changes to footer.phtml (just for be sure it's working), and no changes are made at all.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It worked by changing the System->Config to 'custom' folder inside of parent theme folder.